# Euler Project Problem #3 Optimization Needed

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, factors

Well I was solving Problem 3 from Project Euler, but I just found out that my code is really bad, it would take so much time to finish processing the code and I honestly do not know how to optimize it.

## Problem Statement

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29. 
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

## My Code:

```
function isPrime(x){
    if(x % 2 == 0 && x != 2){
        return false;
    }
    for(j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(x); j+=2){    
        if(x % j == 0 && x != j){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
function euler(){
    const t = 600851475143;
    let maxPrimeDiv = 0;

    for(let j = 3; j <= t; j++){
        if(isPrime(j) && t % j == 0){
            maxPrimeDiv = j;
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return maxPrimeDiv;
}
```

```
console.log(euler());
```

Comment: You don't need to test for primality. If you start with 2 and proceed in sequence 2, 3,4,5, ... then when you find a factor it is *guaranteed* to be prime. Another optimization is, after trying 2 or 3 every prime is of the form 6*k + 1 or 6*k - 1 for k an integer. Finally, once you reach sqrt(n) without finding a factor you know that n is prime. You can combine these to drastically speed up your code.

Comment: Check these https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22largest+prime+factor%22+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Every factor is *not* guaranteed to be prime. If one progresses through the sequence 2, 3, 4, 5, … testing which of these divides the number 12, then, amongst others, 4 and 6 will be (correctly) identified as factors, neither of which are prime. The OP‘s algorithm doesn’t perform any divisions.

Comment: Well of course you have to divide out the prime factors as you find them. The comment is a hint, not a complete algorithm.